# CSS @media rule in pug?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to apply @media rules on pug? I don't know how to adjust my pages' components when the screen size is changed.

I've tried

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px){
    body{
      background: #FF5D50;
    }
}
```

but nothing happens when I change the device on Chrome.

Comment: the media rule you provided works fine. is there any other styling applied to the body overruling your @media rule?

Comment: I have the default style for the body and then inserted that code. I removed the code for the default style and retained the code I showed above and it worked.

Comment: did you try putting `!important` after the color code?

Comment: i haven't tried that

Comment: Ae you sure you're resizing chrome to be equal to 320px wide or narrower? That's how small it would have to be to apply those styles.

Answer (score 1):

All CSS including @media rules should work in Pug templates, you just need to ensure proper indentation below `style.`

```
style.
    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        body {
            background: #FF5D50;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So looks like your rule is overridden. Try make it more specific like `html body` or add `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Media query works once headers are set properly in pug layout:

```
meta(content='width=device-width' initial-scale='1' shrink-to-fit='no' name='viewport')
```